# BEM configuration for react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, vite, bem

I used to work for a company that used BEM to build classNames for react elements, now I'm working on a solo project and would like to use it, and came across this package [rebem-jsx](https://github.com/rebem/rebem-jsx)  but my project is typescript I tried to get it to work with babel, plugin that is called in vite, but it didn't work, have anyone used a similar package with tsx before that he recommends?

Comment: Personally I use BEM with React without a tool. Why would you need a tool? It will mess with your sub-blocks, and it will prevent you from searching a real class name into your code base.

Comment: it's easier than composing the className you enter properties, block="class" elem="elem" mods="mod" will eventually be class__elem_mod, easier to read than writing className="class__elem_mod"